# Right-align string character column in R console output

Tags: r, corpus

I have text snippets split over three columns. I would like to display these three columns in the [KWIC concordance format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_Word_in_Context) in the R console for quick "visual analysis". To this end, the first column needs to be right-aligned, the middle one centred, and the third column left-aligned.

Here is some example data to demonstrate the problem:

```
concordance1 <- c("Well it's not that easy as you can tell I was trying to work out how this", "is working", "but I can't say I understand yet")
concordance2 <- c("they've just", "been having", "more and more trouble")
concordance3 <- c(" sorry I wasn't really engaging Um I", "was thinking", "back to like youth club days...")
data <- as.data.frame(rbind(concordance1, concordance2, concordance3))
```

If I just print data, all three columns are left-aligned and R displays the concordance lines over several rows so it's totally illegible.

```
data
```

So far, the tibble display is the best I could find. It adjusts the width of the table to my console display (see screenshot) which is an improvement. This is a start, but in order to quickly analyse these concordances, I need to be able to **right-align the first column** in the tibble display.

[Tibble display screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGnFL.png)

I'm grateful for any tips as to how this might be achievable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```r
print(mapply(format, data, justify=c("right", "centre", "left")), quote=F)
```

EDIT:

To left-truncate the first columns to a specified maximum width, you could wrap this in a function as follows:

```r
format.kwic <- function(data, width=20) {
    trunc <- function(x, n=20) {
        x <- as.character(x)
        w <- nchar(x)
        ifelse(w > n, paste0("\U2026", substring(x, w-n, w)), x)
    }
    data[,1] <- trunc(data[,1], n=width)
    mapply(format, data, justify=c("right", "centre", "left"))
}
print(format.kwic(data), quote=F)
```

Output:

```
##      V1                     V2           V3                              
## [1,] … to work out how this  is working  but I can't say I understand yet
## [2,]           they've just been having  more and more trouble           
## [3,] … really engaging Um I was thinking back to like youth club days...
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately, like the standard df console display, it does not truncate the start of long strings in the first column. This means that a line may be displayed over two or more rows in the console. This makes it very hard to interpret a concordance line on the fly. I'm looking for this kind of solution but applicable to a tibble.

Comment: would it help to change the width (e.g. options("width"=200))

Comment: I've just experimented with options("width"), but since that doesn't truncate overly long lines either, I sadly cannot find a width that will work for all my concordance lines (which are of various lengths and some are quite long).

Comment: there have been various methods used to truncate long strings for visualization in console, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343682/printing-dataframes-with-long-strings-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379988/is-it-possible-to-truncate-output-when-viewing-the-contents-of-dataframes

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. You can make it a tibble if you want, but it's not necessary.